# Musicality in playing music notes

Tags: piano

I am self taught- piano,
When I play, i hear all the notes, but I don’t “hear the music”!
How do I achieve that?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the op doesn't necessarily mean so much as interpretations, but just to make the playing musical (even if it's not the composer's intention)? That would be my question, too. I may hit all the right keys in the correct beats but when I listen to a pianist's performance I'm like, wow, that's music, what it's supposed to sound like! The linked topic seems to be more for more seasoned pianists.

Comment: @GrandAdagio I'd say Richard's answer there is still important to beginners. It's the "next answer, to the next question," because the conversation goes like this: "Don't just play the notes, do interesting musical stuff." "Ok... what kind of stuff?" And sometimes a big part of the answer is "All the sorts of stuff that the composer figured was so obvious, or so much a part of the performing culture of their day, that they didn't bother spelling out."

Comment: To Sallah: This question hasn't seemed very clear to me. If you were getting at something other than "how to add musically interesting interpretation," please edit.

Comment: Some other questions that might be helpful are https://music.stackexchange.com/q/33799/78419, https://music.stackexchange.com/q/129069/78419, and perhaps https://music.stackexchange.com/q/42975/78419